# Why pre-processor gives a space?

Tags: c-preprocessor, stringification

I want to comment a line using the pre-processor:

```
#define open /##*

#define close */

main()
{
        open commented line close
}
```

when I do `$gcc -E filename.c` I expected

```
/* commented line */
```

but I got

```
/ * commented line */
```

so that the compiler shows an error

Why it is giving an unwanted space ?

Comment: Maybe you should add the "abusing_the_c_preprocessor" tag? ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The preprocessor runs and produces code in a form that the C compiler can understand. It only processes your code once, so even if you *could* produce a `/*` with your `#define`, the compiler would see the `/*` and give you an error because it's not valid C code (it's a preprocessing instruction).

This doesn't seem like a very good thing to do.

Comment: `#define` is the only preprocessing instruction here. `/*` is not a preprocessor instruction, but it's not clear what you're referring to.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: The preprocessor is responsible for removing comments before passing the code to the compiler.

Comment: According to C99 5.1.1.2/3, comments are whitespace and are not preprocessing tokens.

Answer (score 6):

From the GNU C Preprocessor documentation:

> However, two tokens that don't together form a valid token cannot be pasted together. For example, you cannot concatenate x with + in either order. If you try, the preprocessor issues a warning and emits the two tokens. Whether it puts white space between the tokens is undefined. It is common to find unnecessary uses of '##' in complex macros. If you get this warning, it is likely that you can simply remove the '##'.

In this case '*' and '/' do not form a valid C or C++ token.  So they are emitted with a space between them.

(Aside: you are likely to get C compilation errors even if you do manage to insert "comments" into the output of the C preprocessor.  There aren't supposed to be any comments there.)

Answer (score 5):

The error is because `/*` is not a valid token.

As explained from the [CPP doc](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html):

> two tokens that don't together form a valid token cannot be pasted together. For example, you cannot concatenate `x` with `+` in either order.

You can get the error by pasting other nonsense stuff e.g. `/##+` or `+##-`.

---

About the space, it is deliberately inserted to avoid creating a comment and mess up the rest. From the [GCC source code](http://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/trunk/libcpp/macro.c?view=markup):

```
    /* Avoid comment headers, since they are still processed in stage 3.
         It is simpler to insert a space here, rather than modifying the
         lexer to ignore comments in some circumstances.  Simply returning
         false doesn't work, since we want to clear the PASTE_LEFT flag.  */
      if ((*plhs)->type == CPP_DIV && rhs->type != CPP_EQ)
        *end++ = ' ';
```

Answer (score 3):

Because comments are replaced with spaces before (and only before) the preprocessor runs. If you paste together the characters `/` and `*` using the preprocessor, you get `/*` which is just a couple operators. **Edit:** such abuse of `##` technically creates `/*` as a single token, which has undefined behavior. You can paste together `> ## >` or `< %:%: :`, although you shouldn't.

See §6.4.6 of C99 for what tokens you are allowed to construct and 6.10.3.3 for the catenation process.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to comment some code using pre-processor, use

```
#if 0
...
#endif
```